# How to close Kendo UI Autocomplete programmatically

Tags: kendo-ui, autocomplete, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using the Kendo UI Autocomplete Box in a ASP.Net MVC Application.
(KENDO UI for ASP.NET MVC Q1 2016)

The part of the .cshtml code looks like this:

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.Label(Strings.ManagerTimeEffortFormPartial_LabelLookupCustomer, new { @class = "k-label" })
                @Html.TextBox("CustomerId", "", new { style = "display: none;" })
                @(Html.Kendo().AutoComplete()
                .Name("CustomerName")
                .DataTextField("DisplayName")
                .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
                .MinLength(3)
                .DataSource(source =>
                {
                    source.Read(read =>
                    {
                        read.Action("SearchCustomers", "Customer")
                            .Data("onSearchManagerEffortCustomerName");
                    })
                    .ServerFiltering(true);
                })
                .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "k-textbox-fullwidth" })
                .Events(e =>
                {
                    e.Select("onSelectManagerEffortCustomer");

                })
                )
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The element needs to be prefilled with a value. I am doing this after the ui was loaded:

```
   $(function () {

    var customerValue = $("#Project_CustomerName").val();

    var customerNameAutoComplete = $("#CustomerName").data("kendoAutoComplete");
    $("#CustomerName").val(customerValue);

    customerNameAutoComplete.search(customerValue);     

    customerNameAutoComplete.select(customerNameAutoComplete.ul.children().eq(0));
   customerNameAutoComplete.close();


});
```

Calling the "Close" method should close the suggestions (from what I understood in the [documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/autocomplete#methods-close)) but it does not work (the suggestions are still open). If I scroll the window in the ui or click somewhere else it closes immediately, but setting focus programmatically to another element or triggering a click-event via code doesn't help. I could hide/change the DOM-elements one by one, but I don't think this is a good solution, there are too many attributes changing when the item is selected with a mouse click.

Everything else in the code works fine (binding source, selecting the element and so on - I did not post the JS-Code for these parts here). I also tried to play with the "suggest" method without any luck. Any idea or a hint in the right direction?

This is how the autocomplete looks like after calling the "Close" method (still open):
[Screenshot of Autocomplete Box with open suggestions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJuuV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for this... again I got caught by the asynchronous loading trap...
of course I need to wait for the data bound event until i should select the item...

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.Label(Strings.ManagerTimeEffortFormPartial_LabelLookupCustomer, new { @class = "k-label" })
                @Html.TextBox("CustomerId", "", new { style = "display: none;" })
                @(Html.Kendo().AutoComplete()
                .Name("CustomerName")
                .DataTextField("DisplayName")
                .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
                .MinLength(3)
                .Suggest(false)
                .DataSource(source =>
                {
                    source.Read(read =>
                    {
                        read.Action("SearchCustomers", "Customer")
                            .Data("onSearchManagerEffortCustomerName");
                    })
                    .ServerFiltering(true);
                })
                .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "k-textbox-fullwidth" })
                .Events(e =>
                {
                    e.Select("onSelectManagerEffortCustomer");
                    e.DataBound("OnCustomerDataBound");
                })
                )
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
function OnCustomerDataBound() {

        var customerNameAutoComplete = $("#CustomerName").data("kendoAutoComplete");    
        var select = customerNameAutoComplete.ul.children().eq(0);
        customerNameAutoComplete.select(select);
        customerNameAutoComplete.close();


}
  $(function () {

    var customerValue = $("#Project_CustomerName").val();
    var customerId = $("#Project_CustomerId").val();
    var consProjectId = $("#Project_ConsultingProjectId").val();

    var customerNameAutoComplete = $("#CustomerName").data("kendoAutoComplete");
    $("#CustomerName").val(customerValue);
    $("#CustomerId").val(customerId);
    customerNameAutoComplete.search(customerValue);     

    customerNameAutoComplete.trigger("change");
    RefreshDropDownList("ManagerEffortCustomerProjects");
});
```

Now it works perfectly fine! Although it is kind of embarrassing, i will not delete this post. Maybe someone else will need some help to step off the hose...